# Cloudflare translates domain to Cloudflare public IP not my server public IP

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I have a server with public IP (ex: 172.34.12.69). I've configured Cloudflare to point the CNAME Record to Elastic Load Balancer **DNS Name** (mydomain.io -> **DNS Name**), and the ELB will forward it to my server. When I use ping to check the public IP, it points mydomain.io to Cloudflare's public IP:

```
PING mydomain.io (104.21.7.240): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 104.21.7.240: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=38.785 ms
64 bytes from 104.21.7.240: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=39.165 ms
64 bytes from 104.21.7.240: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=36.818 ms
```

When I use **adb** to connect the local android device like: `adb connect mydomain.io:5555`. The domain has been translated to Cloudflare's public IP so the connection could not be established. How can I translate the domain to my server's public ip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create any record in cloudflare do not use cloudflare proxy. (Turn orange arrow to grey). Doing that will remove cloudflare extra protection and dns record will point your server.